# How to solve $\ln(x)-\ln(\ln(x))+\frac{\ln(\ln(x))}{\ln(x)}<4$?

Tags: inequality, logarithms

WolframAlpha gives [$1<x<214.272$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log%28x%29-log%28log%28x%29%29%2Blog%28log%28x%29%29%2Flog%28x%29+%3C+4).

But on top of this specific solution, I am also interested in the general solution for:

$$\ln(x)-\ln(\ln(x))+\frac{\ln(\ln(x))}{\ln(x)}<K$$

With $K$ being a constant positive value.

Therefore, I would like to know how to approach that.

I tried substituting $\ln(x)$ with $z$ in order to reduce the problem to:

$$z-\ln(z)+\frac{\ln(z)}{z}<K$$

But I couldn't make any progress on that.

I also tried substituting $\ln(\ln(x))$ with $z$ in order to reduce the problem to:

$$e^z-z+\frac{z}{e^z}<K$$

But I couldn't make any progress on that either.

Any ideas how to approach this problem will be very much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't look like a problem that can be solved analytically. What makes you think it's possible?

Comment: @ClementYung: I haven't assumed it is possible. I was hoping that it would be. What about $k=4$ specifically?

Comment: It can be reduced to estimation $(1-z)(1-\frac{\ln z}{z})$, if this helps.

Comment: @zkutch: Thanks, but not entirely clear. What should I compare this with? $0$? $K$?

Comment: Unfortunately to some non zero constant $C$. Would you like me to show steps?

Comment: @zkutch: Yes, thank you.

Comment: Wrote as answer, as it's easy to edit and see, but may be it is answer?

Answer (score 1):

$$K>z-\ln(z)+\frac{\ln(z)}{z} = z\left(1- \frac{\ln(z)}{z} \right) + \frac{\ln(z)}{z}-1+1 = (z-1)\left(1- \frac{\ln(z)}{z} \right) +1$$ so
$$(z-1)\left(1- \frac{\ln(z)}{z} \right) <K-1$$
Now taking $$1- \frac{\ln(z)}{z} <\frac{K-1}{z-1}$$
for $K-1>1$ you'll have solution $(0, x_0)$ for some $x_0>0$ which gives us intersection of two graphs. For $K=4$ $x_0>5$. Visually you can see this on [desmos.com](https://www.desmos.com/calculator)